# I have a build error with MinGW and VS Code "g++ not recognized as a cmdlet..."

Tags: c++, build, visual-studio-code, mingw, mingw-w64

I am trying to set up build and run a c++ file in VS Code 2019. I am having build errors after editing the tasks.json file. The environment variable is set to g++ as it should be. So far, I have been following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/DIw02CaEusY).

I attempted changing "command" to"C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe" as recommended in a question thread on GitHub. However, because my c++ file is not in this file path, the program was not able to find it when I built the code. This is what the "command" portion of the tasks.json file should look like:

```
"label": "build calculator adventure",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-o",
                "Calculator-Adventure",
                "Calculator Adventure.cpp"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
```

The `"Calculator-Adventure"` part is my filename. The expected output is for the code to build and create a .exe file for my code, as stated in the tutorial and said in the VS Code Docs.

However, it currently outputs the following into the terminal:

```
> Executing task: ‪‪g++ -g Calculator Adventure.cpp -o Calculator-Adventure <

g++ : The term 'g++' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us, inside the question itself to make it self-contained.

Comment: I think that means `fileName.cpp` does not exist or is in a different folder.

Comment: And remember that while Windows filesystems themselves by default aren't case-sensitive, Unix-like tools and environments could still be.

Comment: Is fileName.cpp supposed to be in the C:\MinGW\bin folder? Or do I have to add the path to my file in the c_cpp_properties.json file?

Comment: ***Is fileName.cpp supposed to be in the C:\MinGW\bin folder?*** No.

Comment: You may want to consult the official documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: The question would be more useful to others if it mentioned why you think the compiler should be able to locate this "fileName.cpp". (Given that name, it's easy to assume that some sort of substitution failed -- i.e. a replacement of "fileName" with the actual file name failed -- but an earlier comment suggests that "fileName.cpp" is in fact the name of a file that is supposed to be compiled.)

Comment: fileName was just a placeholder name I used for the sake of the comment. Would it be more useful in the future to post the actual filename? I will update my question and answer because I was facing two errors. The one mentioned in the question happened because I was following the advice of an answer to a question about the original error. The problem solved in my answer below was for the original error. Let me clear them both up.

Comment: @C0DEWzard It would be more useful in the future to explicitly state in the question that "fileName" is intentionally being used as a placeholder name. Or choose a name more commonly used as a placeholder, such as "foo", "bar", or "baz". Or use the original file name if that does not distract from the question. Up to you.

Comment: @JaMiT Duly noted. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I finally figured it out. What worked for me was adding the file path to the git bash shell (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Git) to the System Environment Variables in the Control Panel (how to do that [here](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/)). Make sure you also have the file path to the MinGW bin folder added to the Environment Variables as well (32bit installer: C:\MinGW\bin) (64bit installer: C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin) Then, restart VS Code and build (Ctrl+Shift+B) again.

Here's my final code for the .json files:

c_cpp_properties.json:

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.17763.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build calculator adventure",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-o",
                "Calculator-Adventure",
                "Calculator Adventure.cpp"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

For more information, check out [this page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw). It is a really detailed step-by-step guide for using the MinGW compiler for C++ in VS Code (read it carefully). If you have any other trouble, take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIw02CaEusY) (same tutorial linked in the question). Hope this helps!

Note: in the docs page I linked, they use the 64bit version of MinGW. It should still work with the 32bit version though. Thanks, to @drescherjm for posting the VS Code Docs!

Comment: Adding the file path to the git bash shell solved the error.  I only changed to the 64bit compiler as that was used in the VS Code Docs. It also says in the Docs to add the file path to whatever shell you use (it recommends bash though). Thanks for the tips!